# Remembering records returned from DB query in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I currently use a query of the form

```
 @recordsfound = Model.where(...)
```

This is located in my controller and returns all records matching the query.  I am using pagination to show a limited number of records at a time.  However, when I select to show the next page the query is run again.  Is there a way to store the records returned in a variable other than an instance variable and therefore not require the query to be rerun?

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean, but if you want the query to only run once per page even on subsequent visits, you can use fragment caching.

Rails will lazy load, and then use the cache when it hits the query in the view.

```
<% results.each do |result| %>
  <% cache result do %>
    <%= result.foo %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If you have any dependent models, you'll have to make sure you expire the cache when they get updated if necessary:

```
belongs_to :result, touch: true
```

Note that if you are in development environment the query will still run. You can change this in your `development.rb` config file. If you do change this setting, don't forget to revert it . Otherwise strange things will happen and you'll waste your time trying to figure out why your changes aren't visible.

```
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

Comment: So would this go in the controller? Thanks

Comment: No, that would go in your view. As you are outputting the results. Rails will lazy load, so the query will run only when the view is hit, at which poing it will use the cache.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will give this a go.  I am purely trying to avoid rerunning the query every time I load the page as I have a very big db.  Ideally I want to run a query when a person conducts a search, then store this in the cache enabling them to see the 2nd page of results without the query running again.  Hopefully what you've already provided will get me in the right direction